# Out of memory cache error when accessing inside the app

Tags: android, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I've searched a lot but I did not understand where to is my error.
First in my app I am getting images from the web if there is no net I am getting them from created database.
I am going to post my ImageLoader class then the memory class then the utils class if there is something wrong please I need some help Thanks in advance.

```
public class ClassImageLoader {

ClassMemoryCache memoryCache=new ClassMemoryCache();
ClassFileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService; 

public ClassImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new ClassFileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id=R.drawable.restlogobutton;
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);

    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ClassUtils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

```
public class ClassMemoryCache {

private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
private long size=0;//current allocated size
private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

public ClassMemoryCache(){
    //use 25% of available heap size
    setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
}

public void setLimit(long new_limit){
    limit=new_limit;
}

public Bitmap get(String id){
    if(!cache.containsKey(id))
        return null;
    return cache.get(id);
}

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
    try{
        if(cache.containsKey(id))
            size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
        cache.put(id, bitmap);
        size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
        checkSize();
    }catch(Throwable th){
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void checkSize() {
    if(size>limit){
        Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated  
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
            size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
            iter.remove();
            if(size<=limit)
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void clear() {
    cache.clear();
}

long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(bitmap==null)
        return 0;
    return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
}
```

}

```
public class ClassUtils {
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{
    final int buffer_size=1024;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;)
        {
          int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
          if(count==-1)
              break;
          os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// replace this methods in your code and try I am not sure it will solve your error but once you can try.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inTempStorage = new byte[32*1024]; 
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

check this link for the ImageLoaderClass:
http://code.google.com/p/vimeoid/source/browse/apk/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/ImageLoader.java

OOM issue check this link:
[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

And if you still get an error then check this one link that I have found after many search and has solved my Problem: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/vYWKY1Y6bUo

Comment: in which class the imageLoader i replace ur code instead of all my code ?

Comment: Iam getting an error on File f=new File(cacheDir, filename); on the cacheDir why is that bro?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/vimeoid/source/browse/apk/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/ImageLoader.java check this link for the ImageLoaderClass and if you still get error then check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966

Answer (score 1):

memory management is a pretty extensive and advanced topic but I'll post a very important tip all in capital letters:

**`DO NOT USE MAP<k,v> !!!`**

the map is keeping references to the imageview (which keeps the activity context) and the bitmaps for ever and it's one of the main reasons you have those memory losses. Further on the reference to context is keep your whole activity in memory, for ever. All very bad ideas.

You'll use a LruCache (available on the compatibility library) to cache the bitmaps, and let only the activity keep reference to the imageviews (either static from the XML or dynamically using an adapter)

here is a Google IO video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbQb1PVjfqM where the guys from Google themselves are showing some best practices around this area, on the 4min mark they show the usage of the LruCache.

Comment: This Video is perfect but iam still beginner in android i got what he said but i dont know exactly where to modify in my code cause my classes are mixed all but thank you u really helped