# Facebook wall stream implementation using graph api in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

My ImageLoader class-------------------->

```
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);


            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=Wall.width;
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE1=Wall.height;
//            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=250;
//         
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
//            while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
////                scale*=2;
            while(true){
                if((width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)||(height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE1))
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            o2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
//            o2.inSampleSize=2;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```

I want to display the facebook wall stream in my application using graph api.

The wall stream consists of following things  1)profile picture
                                               2)name ,posted message,posted image
                                               3)Like,Comment options
  I got the data from facebook graph api
                 https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token="+accesstoken;

In this I got data of page1 and I used "paging" to get the data of second page and same for getting third page.

But when I tried to display the first page,because of more images I am getting

```
Bitmap size exceeds VM Budget error:Out of Memory error
```

I want to know, how the other facebook applications managing this issue,I observed that they are loading  only less number of records at a time.How to do such things,if I got the data in pagewise?

```
public class Wall extends Activity {

    private Button btnSettings,btnLogout,btnUpdate,btnWall,btnCheckin,btnPubfinder,btnCamera;

    public String accesstoken,wallres,str_likevariable="",webserv,currentweb;

    protected static JSONArray jsonArray;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    MyProgressDialog dialog;


     private PullToRefreshListView listView;

     ArrayList<String> msg=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> id=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> objid=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> profimg=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> img=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> pic=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> comment=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> likes=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> weburl=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> like_or_unlike=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> date=new ArrayList<String>();




     ImageLoader imageLoader;
     Handler mHandler;
     View footerView;

     private int previousTotal = 0,j=0;

     public  static int width,height;
     public boolean loading = true,isScrolling,scroll=true,boolisLoad=true,boolDialog=true,addFooter=false;
     MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter;

     static {


       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build());
   }


  //onCreate 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wall);

        //To get device dimensions
        android.view.WindowManager w = getWindowManager(); 
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
       width = d.getWidth(); 
        height = d.getHeight(); 
      System.out.println(width);
      System.out.println(height);

        btnSettings=(Button)findViewById(R.id.settings);
        btnLogout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);
        btnCamera=(Button)findViewById(R.id.camera);
        btnUpdate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.update);
        btnWall=(Button)findViewById(R.id.wall);
        btnCheckin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.checkin);
        btnPubfinder=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pubfinder);

       ButtonListener listener=new ButtonListener();

       btnSettings.setOnClickListener(listener);
       btnLogout.setOnClickListener(listener);
       btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(listener);
       btnWall.setOnClickListener(listener);
       btnCheckin.setOnClickListener(listener);
       btnPubfinder.setOnClickListener(listener);
       btnCamera.setOnClickListener(listener);
       //access token 
        accesstoken=Login.mFacebook.getAccessToken();

        Log.e("accesstoken",accesstoken);

        //first page webservice
        webserv="https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token="+accesstoken;
        Log.e("firstweb",webserv);

        //pullToRefresh Listview
        listView= (PullToRefreshListView ) findViewById(R.id.walldata);
        listView.setDivider(null);
        //footer view
        footerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
//        this.mHandler = new Handler();
        listView.addFooterView(footerView);
//
//        this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable,5000);


        SessionStore.restore(Login.mFacebook, Wall.this);

        SessionEvents.removeAllAuthListener();




        listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

//          @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // Your code to refresh the list contents goes here

                scroll=true; //to keep the scroll at position where it has hits the load more data 

                pic.clear();
                id.clear();
                name.clear();
                msg.clear();
                img.clear();
                profimg.clear();      
                objid.clear();
                comment.clear();
                weburl.clear();
                adapter.clear();
                likes.clear();
                like_or_unlike.clear();
                date.clear();

                addFooter=true; // to add the footer view again after removing in pullToRefresh

                 previousTotal = 0;
                 loading = true;

                listView.removeFooterView(footerView);
                listView.setAdapter(null);

                j=0;

                webserv="https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token="+accesstoken;
                 Log.e("inpull",webserv);

                System.out.println(listView.getCount());
                 doInBack dob=new doInBack();
                 dob.execute(); 
                System.out.println(listView.getCount());

                    Log.e("hi","doback called");


            }
        });
//        


        listView.setOnScrollListener(new  OnScrollListener() {

            private int threshold = 0;
//          
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
////                
                  if (scrollState != 0) {  
                    isScrolling = true; 
                }
                else {   
                   isScrolling = false;  //To load the data when the scroll is in offstate
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }  

            }


          public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
          {     


              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              if (loading) {
                  if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    Log.e("in loading","in load");
                      loading = false;
                      previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                  }
              } 

                   if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount+2) == totalItemCount+1){


                       System.out.println(firstVisibleItem);
                       System.out.println(visibleItemCount);
                       System.out.println(totalItemCount);
                       scroll=false;

                       Log.v("in gridview loading more","grid load");
//                      
                       doInBack dob=new doInBack();
                       dob.execute();  
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                       doback(webserv);
                    loading = true;
                   }
              }
//          }



      });

        doInBack dob=new doInBack();
            dob.execute();     
//        doback(webserv);
        Log.e("hi","doback called");



        }
/

    private class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener{

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.equals( btnSettings)){
            Intent myintent=new Intent(Wall.this,Settings.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            finish();
            }

        else if(v.equals(btnLogout)){
            try {
                String res=Login.mFacebook.logout(Wall.this);

                Log.e("response",res);
                System.out.println(res);
                System.out.println(Login.mFacebook.isSessionValid());

                //if(res.equals("true"))
                //{
                    Intent in=new Intent(Wall.this,Login.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                //}
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

        else if(v.equals(btnUpdate)){
            Update.i=0;
            Intent myintent=new Intent(Wall.this,Update.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            finish();
            }   


        else if(v.equals(btnCamera)){
            Intent myintent=new Intent(Wall.this,CameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            finish();
            }


        else if(v.equals(btnWall)){
//          Intent myintent=new Intent(Wall.this,Wall.class);
//          startActivity(myintent);
//          finish();
            }


        else if(v.equals(btnCheckin)){
            Intent myintent=new Intent(Wall.this,Checkin.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            finish();
            }


        else if(v.equals(btnPubfinder)){
            Intent myintent=new Intent(Wall.this,PubFinder.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            finish();
            }

        }
    }

    class doInBack extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
    {
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        { if(boolDialog){
            dialog=MyProgressDialog.show(Wall.this, null,null);
        }
        }
//      currentweb= webserv;
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(URL... arg0) {

            currentweb=webserv;



//      
            Log.e("hi","doback parsing");


            try
            {   
//              if(urlval>0){
                    wallres=UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl(currentweb);
                    Log.e("wallrespages",wallres);
    }
                JSONObject jobj1=new JSONObject(wallres);

                JSONObject jobj2=jobj1.getJSONObject("paging");
                webserv= jobj2.getString( "next");

                 jsonArray = jobj1.getJSONArray("data");


                 for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                     jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);





                    if(jsonObject.has("message")||jsonObject.has("picture")) {

                        try{


//                        msg[j]=jsonObject.getString("message");
                            if(jsonObject.has("message"))
                            {

                                msg.add(jsonObject.getString("message"));   
                            }
                            else{
                                msg.add("");    
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try{

//                            msg[j]=jsonObject.getString("message");
                                if(jsonObject.has("picture"))
                                {
                                    String firstpicture=jsonObject.getString("picture");
                                    String secondpicture=firstpicture.replaceAll("_s.jpg", "_n.jpg");
                                     Log.e("picurl",secondpicture);
                                     pic.add(secondpicture);

                                }
                                else{
                                    pic.add("");
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }





                        objid.add(jsonObject.getString("id"));



                          JSONObject jobj=jsonObject.getJSONObject("from");
                           name.add(jobj.getString("name"));
                           id.add(jobj.getString("id"));

                           if(jsonObject.getString("type").equals("checkin")){
                               name.set(i,jobj.getString("name")+" "+"is at"+" "+jsonObject.getString("name"));
                            }
                       Log.e("id",id[j]);
                           profimg.add("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id.get(j)+"/picture?type=square");

                           JSONObject commentjobj=jsonObject.getJSONObject("comments");
                            comment.add(commentjobj.getString("count"));

                            if(jsonObject.has("likes")) {

                                   Log.e("likeornot","likre");
                                JSONObject likesjobj=jsonObject.getJSONObject("likes");
                                likes.add(likesjobj.getString("count"));

                               String postid=jsonObject.getString("id");
//                                  graph_or_fql = "fql";
                                    String query = "SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = \'" + postid + "'";

//                                                        Log.d("finalThreadID", finalThreadID);
                                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                    params.putString("method", "fql.query");
                                    params.putString("query", query);
//                                                        Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, new LikesListener());

                                String fqlResponse = Login.mFacebook.request(params);

                                   System.out.println(fqlResponse);

                                   JSONArray JOLikeresponse=new  JSONArray(fqlResponse);

                                  if(JOLikeresponse.length()!=0){
                                   JSONObject JOLikeObject = JOLikeresponse.getJSONObject(0);




                                if ( JOLikeObject.has("likes")) {
                                    String optlike,optlikesarray;
                                    JSONObject optLikes=JOLikeObject;
                                    JSONArray optLikesArray;
                                    try{

                                         optLikes = JOLikeObject.getJSONObject("likes");
                                         optlike="like";
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e){

                                         optlike="unlike";
                                    }
//                                  
                                    if(optlike.equals("like")){

                                    if (optLikes.has("user_likes")) {
                                        String getUserLikes = optLikes.getString("user_likes");

                                        if (getUserLikes.equals("true")) {
                                            like_or_unlike.add("Unlike");
                                        } else if (getUserLikes.equals("false")) {
                                            like_or_unlike.add("Like");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {

                                           like_or_unlike.add("Like");
                                    }
                                } else {

                                       like_or_unlike.add("Like");
                                }

                                }
                                //if likes object is not there in like response
                                else {

                                       like_or_unlike.add("Like");
                                }
                                  }

                               //if the like response Array length is zero   
                                else {

                                       like_or_unlike.add("Like");
                                }//FQL query object

                            }

                    //If likes are not there        
                               else{
                                   likes.add("0");
                                   like_or_unlike.add("Like");
                               }


                            weburl.add(currentweb);

                           Log.e("comment", comment.get(j));



                           String getCreatedTime = jsonObject.getString("created_time");

                           SimpleDateFormat formatter = getDateFormat();
                           ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
                           long then = formatter.parse(getCreatedTime, pos).getTime();
                           long now = new Date().getTime();

                           long seconds = (now - then)/1000;
                           long minutes = seconds/60;
                           long hours = minutes/60;
                           long days = hours/24;

                           String friendly = null;
                           long num = 0;
                           if (days > 0) {
                               num = days;
                               friendly = days + " day";
                           } else if (hours > 0) {
                               num = hours;
                               friendly = hours + " hour";
                           } else if (minutes > 0) {
                               num = minutes;
                               friendly = minutes + " minute";
                           } else if(seconds>0) {
                               num = seconds;
                               friendly = seconds + " second";
                           }
                           else{
                               friendly = "few seconds";
                           }
                           if (num > 1) {
                               friendly += "s";
                           }
                           String postTimeStamp = friendly.toLowerCase() + " ago";
                           Log.e("date",postTimeStamp );
                           date.add(postTimeStamp);

                           j++;
                    }
                    }







            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) { 

            try
            {   if(addFooter){
                 listView.addFooterView(footerView);
            }

                addFooter=false;
                System.out.println(scroll);
                if(scroll){

                 adapter=new MySimpleArrayAdapter(Wall.this,R.layout.wall,pic,name,msg,id,profimg,comment,objid,weburl,likes, like_or_unlike,date);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                  listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

//                      @Override
                        public void run() {

                            listView.onRefreshComplete();
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                if(boolDialog){
                dialog.dismiss();
                }
                }

         else{
//           adapter=new MySimpleArrayAdapter(Wall.this,R.layout.wall,pic,name,msg,id,profimg,bitmap,comment,objid,weburl);
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

//                  @Override
                    public void run() {

                        listView.onRefreshComplete();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
                if(boolDialog){
                dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }



            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if(boolDialog){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    }
            }
            boolDialog=false;       
    }

    }

    private static SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
    }





public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> namear,msgar,idar,profimage,postimage,commentsnum,objectid,urlString,likescount,like_or_ulike,datesofpost;
    TextView name1, message1,comments,commentsnumber, likesnumber,likes,dateofpost;
    ImageView profimg,postimg;
  ImageLoader imageLoader;
  Bitmap[] bitdata;
//  ViewHolder holder ;

//  View rowView;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Activity c,int i,ArrayList<String> postpic, ArrayList<String> names,ArrayList<String> msg,ArrayList<String> id,ArrayList<String> proimg,ArrayList<String> comment,ArrayList<String> objid,ArrayList<String> web,ArrayList<String> likecount,ArrayList<String> unlike_or_like,ArrayList<String> dates) {

      super(c, i, names);
    Log.e("adapter","adap");
    this.context = c;
    this.namear = names;
    this.msgar = msg;
    this.idar = id;
    this.profimage=proimg;
    this.postimage=postpic;
//    this.bitdata=bit;
    this.commentsnum=comment;
    this.objectid=objid;
    this.urlString=web;
    this.likescount=likecount;
    this.like_or_ulike=unlike_or_like;
    this.datesofpost=dates;
   this.imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
  }
//  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
////        View view;
//      TextView title1,id,name1,dispdate,loc;
//      ImageView image,delete,arrow;
//      View view = convertView;
////        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfav_row, parent, false);
//      LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
//      view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.myfav_row, null);


  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            // code to load images

      View rowView=convertView ;
      LayoutInflater inflator =   getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.walldata, null);

     name1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
     message1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
     profimg= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
     postimg= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.picpost);
     comments = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
     likes = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.like);
     commentsnumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.commentnumber);
     likesnumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likesnumber);
     dateofpost = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.datepost);
//     rowView.setTag(holder);
     Log.e("user",idar.get(position));


    Log.e("adapter","adap");
     name1.setText(namear.get(position));
    if(msgar.get(position)!=""){
         message1.setText(msgar.get(position));

    }
    else
    {
         message1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(!isScrolling){
    if(!postimage.get(position).equals(""))
    {try{
         imageLoader.DisplayImage(postimage.get(position).replace(" ", "%20"), postimg) ;
//      Bitmap b= imageLoader.getBitmap(postimage.get(position));
//      postimg.setImageBitmap(b);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    else
    {
         postimg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    }
    try{
      imageLoader.DisplayImage(profimage.get(position).replace(" ", "%20"),  profimg) ;

    }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dateofpost.setText(datesofpost.get(position));
     commentsnumber.setText(commentsnum.get(position));
     likesnumber.setText(likescount.get(position));
     likes.setText(like_or_ulike.get(position));

     likes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
//          if(likes.getText().toString().equals("Like")){
               TextView t=(TextView)v;
              TextView likescountmodify = null;
              View parent = (View) t.getParent();
                if (parent != null) {
                    likescountmodify =  (TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.likesnumber);

                }

                int i=  Integer.parseInt(likescount.get(position));

           if(like_or_ulike.get(position).equals("Like")){
                Log.e("inlike","like");
                like_or_ulike.set(position, "Unlike");
                t.setText(like_or_ulike.get(position));
                UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+objectid.get(position)+"/likes?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post");
//             listView.getAdapter().getItemAt(position);
               j=i+1;
               String s=Integer.toString(j);
            likescount.set(position, s);
            likescountmodify.setText(likescount.get(position));

            }
            else{
                Log.e("unlike","unlike");
                like_or_ulike.set(position, "Like");
                t.setText(like_or_ulike.get(position));
                UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+objectid.get(position)+"/likes?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"DELETE");

                   j=i-1;
                 String s=Integer.toString(j);
                likescount.set(position, s);
                likescountmodify.setText(likescount.get(position));
            }
        }
    });


     comments.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myintent=new Intent(Wall.this,Comments.class);
            myintent.putExtra("name", namear.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("profimg", profimage.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("message", msgar.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("postpic", postimage.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("objectid", objectid.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("commentsnum",commentsnum.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("webservice", urlString.get(position));
            startActivity(myintent);
            finish();

        }
    });

    return rowView;

  }
}
```

please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Share your code please to get a better and instant solution :)

Comment: please find my edited post

Comment: check this link for the Bitmap memory issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606045/out-of-memory-cache-error-when-accessing-inside-the-app/13606461#13606461 
and if you can not solve error then check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

They might be caching the records or posts and they display(load) records visible to the user at that instant. on how to do this, check out this sample application from developer.android.com ->

[displaying-bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Comment: I read this link,where can I find these helper classes to convert imageurl into Bitmaps

Answer (score 0):

You should try to limit the size of the `Bitmap`s that you show close to the size of the image view so that you don't waste memory by having large images in memory when you actually want to show a lower resolution image. I usually use this function to resize an image file to a size closer to the one that I want.

```
// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO: Do something
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: please find my edited post,I attached the decodefile() method which I have used.I want to display the images sizes close to my screen size,so I have taken width,height as parameters for REQUIRED_SIZE, REQUIRED_SIZE1.so,I want to scale the images upto that screen size,because I want the images to be as big as possible. I found there is issue with Bitmaps.How to handle Large bitmaps?

Comment: Does this happen always with the same image? It might be possible that there is one image that is too big to be even read as a byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

// Use Option class instead of BitmapFactory.Options

```
Options opts = new Options(); 
                    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts); 
                    Log.e("optwidth",opts.outWidth+""); 
                    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false; 
                    if(opts.outWidth>500){ 
                            opts.inSampleSize = 4; 
                            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts); 
                    } 
                    else mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);
```

Note: It can degrades the quality of Image but surely it can remove your Out of memory error  for bitmap according to my knowledge. for more details check this link: [Handling large Bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220949/handling-large-bitmaps)