# OOM error for png file having size greater than 2.3MB

Tags: java, android, bitmap

My application gets crashed on opening a .png file which is having size of 2.5MB. This file is of high resolution.Im getting OOM error.

The piece of code which causes the error is:

```
long sizeInMB = imageFile.length()/(1024*1024);
if(sizeInMB > 2){
    int inSampleSize = (int) (sizeInMB/5);
    if(sizeInMB%5 > 0){
        inSampleSize++;
    }
    Options opts = new Options();
    opts.inSampleSize=inSampleSize;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, opts);    
}else{
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
}
```

The line `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath)` causes the error.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath)` causes the error something seems to go wrong because the other if-branch (`bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, opts);`) should be executed, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this may be it will solve your problem.

```
Options opts = new Options(); 
  opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts); 
  Log.e("optwidth",opts.outWidth+""); 
  opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false; 
  if(opts.outWidth>500){ 
          opts.inSampleSize = 4; 
          mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts); 
  } 
  else mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);
```

I have added code for the width size, you can also add as per your requirement for height.

if you want more information then check this link it will help you: [Handling large Bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220949/handling-large-bitmaps)

Other suggested link is here: [Out of memory cache error when accessing inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606045/out-of-memory-cache-error-when-accessing-inside-the-app/13606461#13606461)

Answer (score 2):

Because in your case 2MB bitmap might take around 10MB of memory

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) on how to load large bitmaps